# How to compute the limit $\lim\limits_{q \rightarrow 1} (1-q)^3 \sum_{n>0} n^{1+\epsilon} q^n$ for $\epsilon \in (0,1)$

Tags: limits, special-functions

I am able to show that $\lim\limits_{q \rightarrow 1} (1-q)^3 \sum_{n>0} n q^n  = 0 $
and $ \lim\limits_{q \rightarrow 1} (1-q)^3 \sum_{n>0} n^2 q^n  = 2$ and now I want to prove that

$$ \lim\limits_{q \rightarrow 1} (1-q)^3 \sum_{n>0} n^{1+\epsilon} q^n = 0 $$

for $\epsilon \in (0,1)$. Do you guys have any hints for me doing so? I can't use the methods which I used to proof the first two statements because they are just valid for integral exponents of $n$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Mathematica 9 produces 0 by $$In[1]:=Assuming[epsilon > 0,
 Limit[PolyLog[-1 - epsilon, q]*(1 - q)^3, q -> 1]]$$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we recognize that the series in question is a polylogarithm,

$$
\newcommand{\Li}{\operatorname{Li}}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^\alpha q^n = \Li_{-\alpha}(q),
$$

then we can take advantage of the [alternate representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Series_representations) (specifically the second equation under #2 in the link)

$$
\Li_{-\alpha}(q) = \Gamma(1+\alpha) (-\log q)^{-\alpha-1} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\zeta(-\alpha-n)}{n!} \,(\log q)^n
$$

which holds for $|\log q| < 2\pi$ and $\alpha \neq -1,-2,-3,\ldots$.  As $q \to 1^-$ the series on the right converges to $\zeta(-\alpha)$ and the term on the left blows up (if $\alpha > -1$).  Since $\log q \sim q-1$ as $q \to 1$ we may conclude that

$$
\lim_{q \to 1^-} (1-q)^{\alpha+1}\Li_{-\alpha}(q) = \Gamma(1+\alpha)
$$

for all $\alpha > -1$.

Comment: @ Antonio Vargas: Your answer is in contradiction to the output of Mathematica 9 and the plot of the expression under the limit.

Comment: @user64494 how so?

Comment: @ Antonio Vargas: See the Mathematica 9 command in my comment to the question. I hope you can plot the expression on your own.

Comment: @user64494 I have plotted the expression on my own and I believe you have misread my answer.  Note that there is an $\alpha+1$ in the exponent in the limit, not $3$.  Mathematica verifies my result: `Manipulate[Plot[{(1-q)^(a+1) PolyLog[-a,q],Gamma[1+a]},{q,1/2,1},AxesOrigin->{1/2,0}],{a,-1+1/2,3}]`

Comment: @ Antonio Vargas: You are right, but the exponent 3 is written in the question. Of course, your answer implies that the limit under consideration equals zero.

Comment: @user64494 yes, and the limit written in my answer provides all that is needed to find that limit: if $\alpha + 1 < 3$ then clearly $$\lim_{q \to 1^-} (1-q)^{3}\Li_{-\alpha}(q) = 0,$$ and if $\alpha + 1 > 3$ then $$\lim_{q \to 1^-} (1-q)^{3}\Li_{-\alpha}(q) = \infty.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot Antonio! Do you have another reference for this? There is no good reference on the wikipedia page and I just find papers using this without references.

Comment: @henrik691 I would check the two references given on wikipedia for the integral representation using the Hankel contour: Whittaker & Watson 1927, § 12.22, § 13.13 and Gradshteyn & Ryzhik 1980, § 9.553.  Using this it's apparently possible to derive the series I used; the steps are outlined on wikipedia in the section I linked to in the answer.

Comment: Just in case someone is interested: A reference for the alternative representation is http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0701743.pdf (Cor 1.2) or http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/exp-math-1/fulltext.pdf .